# Adobe Experience Manager and Adobe Media Server

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, aem

**Does anybody know how to use Adobe Experience Manager.I have been assigned to do a project (video Sharing Site) using AEM and AMS. And i can't find any source on internet explaining it.I went through the adobe site explaining how to use these tool but i am unable to understand.if possible please guide me to a specific source explaining how to use it.
Thanks in advance **

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) is the new brand name for a product Adobe purchased. It has had several names in the past but the most notable is Communiqué or CQ (CQ5).  Searching the web for CQ5 will return many articles and posts.

Adobe purchased CQ from the *Day* company and much of the documentation is still hosted on that domain.

See these links for numerous articles related to working in AEM.

- [Adobe Experience Manager Documentation](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current.html)
- [How to Create a Fully Featured Internet Website](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/howto/website.html)